# how to add event handler to programatically created checkboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gridview

This is my code for adding a check box progrmatically but it doesnt let me add an event onchecked

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.EnableViewState = true;
        chk.Enabled = true;

        chk.ID = "chkb";
        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;


        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(chk);

        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
    }
```

when I try to add this:

```
chk.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
I get this error : 
"The name 'checkBox_CheckedChanged' does not exist in the current context",
```

even though I have already added this function:

```
   private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
   Response.Write("in check changed object");
  }
```

Comment: Capital letter? `chk.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;`

Comment: C# is Case Sensitive so the error is correct if your code is an exact copy.

Comment: Capital letter for `CheckBox_CheckedChanged`

Comment: All, please don't post answers in the comments. Comments are for asking for clarification on the question, not providing an answer.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I like to give people the benefit of the doubt and don't immediately assume they missed something trivial in case the code is an example they typed free-hand and not actually their running code.

Comment: @randcd: In some cases that's fair, but the error message that's part of the question makes it fairly obvious that the character casing is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

C# is case-sensitive. Your function is named `CheckBox_CheckedChanged`, but you are attempting to attach an event handler for a function named `checkBox_CheckedChanged` (note the upper- vs. lowercase "c" at the beginning).

Comment: Hi thank you , you were right I had to capitalize the first C.  But now that I dont get an error, the function is not working, when I check or uncheck the box it never goes to the event handler.    Can that be answered here or do I have to make a new question ?

Comment: @Dianacastillo: To keep things simple, please make a new question.

Answer (score 4):

C# is case sensitive.

You should create this method:

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write("in check changed object");
}
```

or, use your method and connect it like this:

```
chk.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
```

A good way to avoid these kind of errors, is to first implement the handler (or at least define it), then let de IDE finish the typing for you.

Comment: checkBox_CheckedChanged to CheckBox_CheckedChanged